# React routing renders two urls at the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have a simple routing that looks like this:

```
<Switch>
  <div className="privateContent">
    <Route exact path="/games/new">
      <PrivateRoute isLogged={loggedIn}>
        <CreateGame />
          </PrivateRoute>
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/games/:id">
      <PrivateRoute isLogged={loggedIn}>
        <ShowGame />
      </PrivateRoute>
    </Route>
```

my react routing version is `5.2.0` and according to what i have read about it, when using `Switch` it should render the FIRST path it matches, HOWEVER, when i try to reach `games/new` BOTH of `<ShowGame />` and `<CreateGame />` get rendered

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `<div className="privateContent">` above all routes - `<Switch>` works as expected when all `<Route>`s are direct children of `<Switch>`.

Put this `div` above `<Switch>`  and it should work.

Comment: when i do that i get `JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts` - i think this error was the reason i put the div there in the first place

Comment: but overall you are right, it works